# Issue with displaying Chartjs annotation elements in Nextjs

Tags: d3.js, charts, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am transferring my CRA to a Nextjs and I am having a bit of an issue with anything that uses the `<canvas>` element. The charts and data are mostly there, but my annotations are now missing from the charts. I have tried importing everything with the [dynamic function](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) for the parent element, but it still seems to not show the missing features.

I am also seeing some weird things happening on an arcgis map which is not visualizing 3d elements on a `<canvas>`. So my guess is that this has something with the way that canvas or d3 interact with the browser.

```
// parent component
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
} from 'chart.js';
// import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { ArrowRight } from '../../icons/ArrowRight';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { chartOptions } from '../../lib/chartOptions';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Chart = dynamic((): any => import('react-chartjs-2').then((m: any) => m.Chart), {
  ssr: false,
});

ChartJS.register(
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
);

export const MarkupCard = ({ item }: any) => {
  const chartRef = useRef();
  const userName = item.user_id.split('@')[0];

  return (
    <div className="w-2/3 pb-10 mx-auto border-2 border-blue items-center rounded-lg my-4 py-4 flex flex-row justify-between">
      <div className="w-full text-left pl-4 pb-6 h-72">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-row justify-between">
          <h2 className="text-lg font-bold">{userName} Marked up a chart</h2>
          <div className=" w-1/3 text-right pr-4">
            <h2>
              {moment(item.created_at)
                .tz(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TIMEZONE ?? '')
                .format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a')}
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Route: {item.routeLongName}</h2>
        <Chart
          style={{ height: '100px', width: '99%' }}
          ref={chartRef}
          plugins={item.details.options.plugins}
          className="trips-chart"
          type="line"
          options={chartOptions(item.details.options, item.details.annotations)}
          data={item.details.chartData}
        />
      </div>
      <Link href={`/app/markupDetail/${item.id}`}>
        <button className="mx-6 h-full flex">
          <ArrowRight />
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// chart component
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { supabase } from '../../client';
import { actions } from '../../store';
import { SocialNote } from '../../types';
import { Card } from './Card';

const SocialFeed = () => {
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState<SocialNote[]>([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadPage = async () => {
    dispatch(actions.setLoaded(true));
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('notes')
      .select('*')
      .order('last_update', { ascending: false });

    if (data) {
      setFeed(data);
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  };

  useEffect((): (() => void) => {
    loadPage();
    return () => supabase.removeAllSubscriptions();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full mx-auto overflow-y-auto">
      {feed.map((item, key) => (
        <Card key={key} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SocialFeed;
```

```
// chartoptions.js
export const chartOptions: any = (options: any, annotations: any) => {
  const { title } = options;
  const { tooltip } = options.plugins;
  return {
    title,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index' as const,
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: { annotations: annotations },
      tooltip,
      legend: {
        position: 'top' as const,
      },
      title,
    },
  };
};
```

```
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

CRA

[image: CRA sample]

Nextjs

[image: Nextjs example]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to register `Annotations` in `ChartJS.register()`

This was not the case for React, but was required for Nextjs

```
import Annotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

ChartJS.register(
  Annotation,
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
);
```